# Fullcalendar --- Add / change Optioions on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have found this in the source code:

```
// function for adding/overriding defaults
function setDefaults(d) {
    $.extend(true, defaults, d);
}
```

I added

```
fc.setDefaults = setDefaults;
```

to have access to this function. Now i try to change some options and render the whole calendar with them, but nothing happens.

```
$.fullCalendar.setDefaults({
   axisFormat:"H:mm"
});
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
```

Is there any way to get / set the options after the calendar created?

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to do ?

Comment: If u want to drop an event from the outside, Fullcalendar will use the "defaultEventMinutes" property for the placeholder's size. I have events with different duartions, so i have to change this option as the user starts to drag an event from the outside.

Comment: As I'm understand, You need use `eventDrop()` function. See details in   docs http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/